# Unable to hide "Add question" menu item in settings menu for survey in SP2010

Tags: 2010, custom-actions, survey-list

I try to hide standard element "Add question" in settings menu for survey list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction 
    Id="a3b18ac6-248f-45c5-8663-a1d02cbd0ace"
    GroupId="SettingsMenuForSurvey"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" />
</Elements>
```

But it doesn't work. I don't understand why, could you please help me?